# MUI: How to delete selected rows in DataGrid programmatically?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm creating a file list with MUI `DataGrid`. The user able to check the checkbox in `DataGrid` to make their selection. I want the checkbox to reset after the user perform some action such as delete the selected file.

The problem I'm facing is after I perform the delete action, the checkbox are still checked in the same spot. For example before I press the delete button:

[image]

After I press the delete button:

[image]

The checkbox are still checked on the second row. How do I reset the checkbox programmatically?

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState([]); // To keep selected file
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]); // To keep uploaded file

const deleteSelectedFile = () => {
  const filteredFileList = files.filter(
    (item) => !selectedFile.includes(item)
  );
  setFiles(filteredFileList);
};

 <DataGrid
    rows={displayFile ? displayFile : []}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={3}
    checkboxSelection
    onSelectionModelChange={({ selectionModel }) =>
      setSelectedFile(selectionModel)
    }
  />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`selectionModel` is not an array of `RowData`, but `RowId`, so in your delete handler, you need to check if the `selectionModel` includes an `item.id`, not `item`:

```
const deleteSelectedFile = () => {
  const filteredFileList = files.filter(
    (item) => !selectedFile.includes(item.id) 
  );
  setFiles(filteredFileList);
};
```

And because you're using [controlled selection](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/selection/#controlled-selection), you need to provide the `selectionModel` props to the `DataGrid` too:

```
const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([]);
```

```
<DataGrid
  {...props}
  onSelectionModelChange={setSelectionModel}
  selectionModel={selectionModel} // add this line
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67209637/how-to-reset-the-check-box-in-material-ui-data-grid-programmatically]

Comment: This requires an update, delete button no longer working.

Comment: @ReactPotato I've updated the answer to v5. The API should be simpler than before.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, Controlled selection in datagrid

```
 <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        checkboxSelection
        onSelectionModelChange={(newSelection) => {
          setSelectionModel(newSelection.selectionModel);
        }}
        selectionModel={selectionModel}
        {...data}
      />
      <div aria-hidden onClick={() => setSelectionModel([])}>
        deselect all
      </div>
 </div>
```

> onSelectionModelChange & selectionModel props can be used to control the selection values in data-grid.

Refer this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xen7q?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: This helped me :3 thank you