# How to clear selection of checkbox from DataGrid MUI via code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a delete function where it deletes an item however it doesn't unselect the item when is deleted and it won't disappear unless I manually unselect/uncheck it.

Is there a way to remove selection via code ?
I tried the following from an answer but it didn't work for me:

`DataGrid.UnselectAllCells()`

This is what I have:

Inside my DataGrid:

```
checkboxSelection
        onSelectionModelChange = {(id) => {
          setSelectionModel(id);
          const selectedIDs = new Set(id);
          const selectedRowData = librosData.filter((row) =>
            selectedIDs.has(row.id)
          );
        }
```

OnClick for delete item

```
onClick={() => {
              const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
              librosData.filter((x) =>
              selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => {

         ... Some code that deletes and update to firebase (working)
                DataGrid.UnselectAllCells()
                 

              })
            }}
```

Comment: Please check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67209637/material-ui-how-to-reset-the-checkbox-in-datagrid-programmatically-after-deleti It maybe help you

Comment: I'll check it, thanks

Comment: found an answer there on the second answer  idk why I complicated myself on trying to code an answer when I can just make the selections = blank. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67209943/7206191)